# Zabbix - Macro {$MYSQL.DSN} without odbc.ini entry

Tags: zabbix

Is there a way to configure `{$MYSQL.DSN}` without `odbc.ini` entry? Not necessary need to be using `{$MYSQL.DSN}`, but where can I only use connection string without `odbc.ini` in host configuration page from zabbix?

Something like `{$MYSQL.DSN} = db.odbc.select[,"DRIVER={MariaDB};SERVER=192.168.0.112;DATABASE=teste;USER=danilo;PASSWORD=test123;OPTION=3;"]`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible since version 5.0 of Zabbix: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/5.0/en/manual/introduction/whatsnew500#odbc-monitoring-without-dsn

An example of what a connection string would look like in the item key in Zabbix (always try to use [user macros](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/6.0/en/manual/config/macros/user_macros) to configure values such as the database name, MySQL server address, username and password):

```
db.odbc.get[your_sql_query,,"Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc8w.so;Database={$MYSQL.DATABASE};Server={$MYSQL.SERVER};Port={$MYSQL.PORT}"]
```

It seems that the official Zabbix documentation doesn't provide a very clear example of how to do this, but if you search [on this page](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/6.0/en/manual/config/items/itemtypes/odbc_checks) for "db.odbc.get" you will find an example.

[MySQL documentation on how to install the ODBC connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-installation-binary-unix.html).

Below is an example of how the ODBC driver can be installed in the [official zabbix-server Docker image](https://www.zabbix.com/container_images) (in this example, Zabbix was running on an Ubuntu 22.04 64-bit ARM architecture):

1. Download the ODBC driver: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/
2. Extract the archive:

```
tar zxvf mysql-connector-odbc-8.1.0-linux-glibc2.28-aarch64.tar.gz
```

3. The extra directory contains two subdirectories, lib and bin. Copy their contents to the proper locations on your system:

```
cp bin/* /usr/local/bin
cp lib/* /usr/local/lib
```

4. Register the driver:

```
myodbc-installer -a -d -n "MySQL ODBC 8.1 Unicode Driver" -t "Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc8w.so"
```

5. Verify that the driver is installed and registered using the ODBC manager, or the myodbc-installer utility:

```
myodbc-installer -d -l
```

And of course, don't forget that when configuring your Zabbix Server (or Zabbix Proxy) you need to have at least 1 instance of the ODBC poller ([StartODBCPollers parameter](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/6.0/en/manual/appendix/config/zabbix_server))